# Get the selected index in a LongListSelector

Tags: vb.net, xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I'm using a LongListSelector for a WP8 app. I searched on several websites but did not found if there was a way to know the index of the item the user taped in the List.
If anyone has an idea, it would be nice.
Thanks

`

```
        <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="ListeNotes" Height="535" Width="426" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" Margin="54,0,0,0">

            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Titre}"/>

                </DataTemplate>

            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>

        </phone:LongListSelector>
```

`

Comment: Yes, but in what context? Post your code.

Comment: Did not understand the question... It's just when the user selects an item, it opens a second page to edit the item. It's a note-taking app.

Comment: Which code ? I don't have anything in VB, I don't know how to do... I just know I have to catch it on the SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles ListeNotes.SelectionChanged event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create in code-beind or ViewModel (depending on what are you using), public variable

```
Public Int32 itemSelectedIndex {get;set;} //This is a public variable, therefore add it inside your class
```

and bind it to `SelectedIndex` as following:

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="ListeNotes" Height="535" Width="426" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" Margin="54,0,0,0" SelectedIndex ="{Binding itemSelectedIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}">
```

don't forget to add datacontext reference in code behind

```
Public void MainWindow()
{
InitializeComponents();
this.DataContext = this;//this makes sure that you can bind public varibles to XAML
}
```

Afterwards you simply reference itemSelectedIndex anywhere in your code and it will return selected value (e.g. `System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(itemSelectedIndex.ToString());`

Comment: I put the first code in my MainPage, did not work (I think it's C# and the conversion tools I found did not work...). Second question : am I supposed to put it in my main class ? And the second code, I put it in the XAML Code but where ? You can see my LLS code in the main topic.

Comment: I have just edited my answer. Hope you can make it work this time! :)

Comment: OK, this is C# but I managed to put it in VB. So the problem now is `The member SelectedIndex is not recognized or not accessible.`  And `The property SelectedIndex is not findable in the type LongListSelector.`

Comment: You can find my MainPage class here : http://pastebin.com/a8UBMj3P
And my XAML code for the LLS is

Comment: `<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="ListeNotes" Height="535" Width="426" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="36" Margin="54,0,0,0" SelectedIndex ="{Binding _itemSelectedIndex, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Titre}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>`

Answer (score 0):

In the handler:

```
SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles ListeNotes.SelectionChanged`
```

The "sender" is the `ListBox`.  So all you have to do is cast "sender" to `ListBox`, and use its `SelectedIndex` property.

```
Dim listBox As ListBox = CType(sender, ListBox)
Dim tappedIndex = listBox.SelectedIndex
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. unfortunately, it won't work as I thought :( I'm working with a LongListSelector, not a ListBox. It's simply showing me this error message : `Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.LongListSelector' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox'.`

Comment: And the LongListSelector does not have a selected index property as far as I (and Visual Studio) know.

Answer (score 0):

you can get it via

```
Dim num As Integer = (sender as LonglistSelector).Datasource.IndexOf((sender as LonglistSelector).SelectedItem)
```

Comment: I had to edit it to make it "work" and removed the as LongListSelector twice. But then I get this error :
The library 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateSetComplex' is not defined.
and 
The library 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet' is not defined.

Comment: for which content this library needed

Answer (score 0):

The solution was not found... 
In fact I just said the user can't have twice the same Note object, and I use the IndexOf method in my List(Of Note) to get the index of the SelectedItem in the LongListSelector.